# SpriteKit drops frame rate when text message is received

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

Working on a SpriteKit platform game with tile collisions using TMX files, parsed with JSTileMap.

When I get a text message the frame rate drops, which isn't really a huge problem most of the time, but sometimes drops so much that collision detection won't work, and the player will go through the floor and die. 
:'(

Any ideas on how to minimize the frame rate drop?

Testing on iphone 6,5c,5s and iPadAir 1stgen.

thanX in advanced!!